# Is there an example on how to use map to loop through complex elements in typescript?

Tags: json, typescript

I am trying to loop through a complex object that has 'inner objects'.  Using map, I can only go one level below.  How can I use map and typescript loop in the levels below.  When I am using map to go in the second level, it`s giving me error.

structure in json

```
{
  "PAYMENTS": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "userID": 1,
      "month": "March 2015",
      "details": {
        "item1": {
          "amount": "1000",
          "date": "01/03/2015",
          "id": 2
        },
        "item2": {
          "amount": "2000",
          "date": "03/03/2015",
          "id": 3
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "userID": 1,
      "month": "April 2015",
      "details": {
        "item1": {
          "amount": "100",
          "date": "01/04/2015",
          "id": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created 2 interfaces

```
export interface IPaymentDetailEntity {
  id: number;
  date: Date;
  amount: string;
}

export interface IPaymentEntity {
  id:number;
  month:string;
  userID:number;
  details:IPaymentDetailEntity[]
}
```

In order to loop through the objects, I am trying

```
{payments.map(paymentDetails => (
  <div key={paymentDetails.id}>
    {paymentDetails.month} {paymentDetails.userID}
  //this part is not working  {paymentDetails.details.map(item => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <span>{item.date}</span>
        <span>{item.amount}</span>
      </div>
    ))}
```

Comment: details is not an array but an object so change details:IPaymentDetailEntity[] to details:IPaymentDetailEntity in the IPaymentEntity interface and then use Object.keys(paymentDetails.details).forEach(key => {
    console.log( paymentDetails[key]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

details is not an array but an object so change details:IPaymentDetailEntity[] to details:IPaymentDetailEntity in the IPaymentEntity interface

Change

```
   export interface IPaymentEntity {
        id:number;
        month:string;
       userID:number;
       details:IPaymentDetailEntity[]
   }
```

To

```
  export interface IPaymentEntity {
        id:number;
        month:string;
       userID:number;
       details:IPaymentDetailEntity
   }
```

Then, you can use Object.key to iterate details object and .map on it to get id, date and amount of items like below

```
   {payments.map(paymentDetails => (
    <div key={paymentDetails.id}>
         {paymentDetails.month} {paymentDetails.userID}
        {paymentDetails.details && Object.keys(paymentDetails.details).map(detail=> (
          <div key={paymentDetails.details[detail].id}>
              <span>{paymentDetails.details[detail].date}</span>
              <span>{paymentDetails.details[detail].amount}</span>
         </div>
     ))}
```

Comment: I am having the error message [ts] Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | number | undefined'. [2322] on the line <div key={detail[key].id>

Comment: @jupiter sailormoon I have updated my answer please take the updated code and try

Comment: It is still giving error ts] Cannot find name 'key'. [2304] on the lin e <div key={detail[key].id}>

Comment: @jupiter sailormoon sorry my bad. You can try with updated code now